# Como resolver Failed: Hostload exceeded en google search console?

Tags: wordpress, url, google-search-console, multi-index

Quiero encontrar una solución para este problema, he intentado indexar mi sitio web en la consola de búsqueda de google, pero me sale un error "Failed: Hostload exceeded". mi proveedor de hosting dice que es un problema de google y que el servidor funciona bien. Necesito indexar las páginas y los artículos que proporciona google no me sirven como solución. ¿alguien sabe o conoce alguna otra solución que no sea esperar unos minutos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que es un problema puntual en la plataforma de Google ([ver este artículo](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-console-failed-hostload-exceeded-36252.html)). Si el error sigue apareciendo, es cuestión de esperar a que Google resuelva el problema. Si necesitas urgente una determinada URL indexada, la puedes someter manualmente.

Comment: Como se puede someter manualmente?

Comment: En el panel de la izquierda seleccionas **Inspección de URLs**, luego pones la URL que quieres indexar en la barra superior, que tiene una lupa a la derecha y presionas enter. Si no está indexada lo hará, y si está indexada te lo dirá. En mi caso esa barra aparece siempre en la parte superior. Cualquier URL que pegues ahí, al darle a Enter la indexará si no lo está.

Answer (score 0):

El error **Hostload exceeded** está explicado en la [documentación de Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en#zippy=%2Csite-wide-availability-issues):

> **Hostload exceeded**: Your site seems to be at maximum capacity for Google crawling or inspection requests. Google can't run tests until
> your traffic load (as estimated by Google) drops.
>
> ---
>
> **Se excedió la carga del host**: su sitio parece haber excedido la capacidad máxima para las solicitudes de inspección o rastreo de
> Google. Google no puede ejecutar pruebas hasta que su carga de tráfico
> (según lo estimado por Google) disminuya.

Esto puede estar ocurriendo a causa de solicitudes excesivas de rastreo de tu sitio web, por ejemplo, algún script que tengas dedicado a ello y que se esté lanzando de forma indiscriminada.

O puede ocurrir puntualmente por sobrecarga en los servidores de Google, según [este post](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-console-failed-hostload-exceeded-36252.html) y algunos tweets incluídos en él, parece que Google experimentó problemas en ese sentido alrededor del 20 de octubre.

Si tienes prisa en indexar una o varias páginas, lo puedes hacer directamente, copiando / pegando la URL en la barra superior de Search Console y pulsando en la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Allí verás si la página está indexada o no, podrás solicitar que sea indexada de nuevo si ha cambiado, podrás ver la página rastreada, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]